# Is it possible to make a script that can open up a application from "hidden apps" arrow in the right corner?

Tags: windows, powershell, citrix

I work with a application called Citrix (Connection Center) and sometimes, it times out the application its running.

When it does this, you manually have to click the Citrix Connection Center, then go to the application that has timed out, and log out.

I was wondering if you can make a script that goes into the application, than logs out. That's it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an automation script to do that using selenium and python